# What to do when a user logs out of Facebook but is still logged-in on my site

Tags: django, facebook

I have a website which users can sign up to using Facebook Connect (with the new OAuth 2.0 stuff). Now when a user logs out of *Facebook* they remain logged-in on *my site*.

I'm not using the JavaScript SDK as I don't like the "magic behind the curtains". So what should I do when a user logs out of Facebook? Should I care at all? I get the feeling I should try to catch this somehow and log them out of my site as well.

I'm using Django with a custom authentication backend for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do anything**. You are using facebook as means of authentication. The fact that the user logged out of facebook means nothing for that matter - He's stil the same user.

Do the users think of your site as a part of facebook? I guess not (assuming its not a facebook app, just a login via facebook). Then it would be surprising and counterintuitive from the user's perspective to find he's also logged out of your site when he only logged out of facebook.

Comment: Makes sense, I hadn't thought about it like that.

Comment: It is a little more complicated than this if you are using the JS SDK though. When a user logs out of Facebook the javascript methods stop working and there doesn't seem to be any way to tell it's happened.